# N distinct balls in K distinct boxes with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

How many ways are there to put *N* distinct balls in *K* distinct boxes such that each box has a max of *C* balls? Ordering of balls within boxes is not relevant.

For instance, the ways you can distribute $5$ distinct balls in $3$ distinct bins would be just $3^5$. But if we place the constraint that each bin can have at the max of $3$ balls, we are left only with the possibilities = $\{(3,2,0)\times3!, (3,1,1)\times(3!/2!), (2,2,1)\times(3!/2!)\}$ instead of the total $3^5$ possibilities.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Take a [tour]. We are NOT a Homework Answering Service. And so your question--no context nor effort shown--makes many of us salty. For similar reasons, your question also goes against the MSE Guidelines. So edit, telling us where this question came from and your efforts thus far. Pls & thx

Comment: @Mike Updated the question. Let me know if any more clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple closed formula, but you can give an answer using exponential generating functions. The number of ways to distribute $n$ distinct items into $k$ distinct boxes with a capacity of $C$ is
$$
n!\cdot [x^n]\left(\sum_{i=0}^{C} \frac{x^i}{i!}\right)^k
$$
Here, $x$ is a "dummy variable", and the notation $[x^n]f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial $f(x)$.

This formula is useful, because any computer algebra system can compute it for you. For example, here is how you use Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica to determine there are $210$ ways to distribute $5$ distinct balls into $3$ distinct bins, each with a capacity of $3$ balls: [Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=n%21+*+Coefficient%5B%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%21%2Bx%5E3%2F3%21%29%5Ek%2C+x%5En%5D+where+n+%3D+5%2C+k+%3D+3).

The reason this works is that when you expand out the above product, and collect all terms with a factor of $x^n$, then you get a sum of fractions like $$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!},$$ where $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ is a list of numbers summing to $n$, each being an integer between $0$ and $C$. This represents the distribution where the $j^\text{th}$ box has $n_j$ balls, for $j\in \{1,\dots,k\}$. For more information about the exponential generating function method, see *generatingfunctionology*, chapter 3, which is available for free online.